# Setting font-size to result in exactly x/window.width per monospace character with CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design

- I have this string line which has for example exactly 100 characters.
- I want to set it's font-size such that the line, starting at exactly pixel 0 of the web page, would end at the final pixel exactly.
- The font is monospace so I assume so i assume i'm aiming towards setting the font-size to 1/100 of the window size.

PROBLEM:
* font-size refers to the height of the font! should i not expect a monospace font to be square ratio regard width and height?

An attempt:

```html
<body>
  <span>
    123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_
  </span>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}
span {
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

this did not result in the wanted outcome. However, setting the `font-size: 1.82` did result in it. But it's a bit shaky I guess to use such a random ratio setting and I was interested if there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: I don't believe there's a CSS-only solution. There is `font-size-adjust`, but that too works on the height instead of the width. For this, you will have to resort to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to not use `font-family: monospace`, because you are *guaranteed* to get different fonts on different browser/OS combinations. So use a real font, which leads to...

Step 2: use a real fond that you load as a webfont from your own server, so you control the exact version of the font people will be using. Because merely using a font by name in the assumption that font exists on everyone's OS, or even assuming something like google fonts will always only send one exact version, is guaranteed to fail, too.

And then step 3: look up what the em size as well as glyph width is that your chosen monospace font use, so that you can base your font-size on values that you know are applicable for *every* user, because you've ensured *exactly* which font will be used to style your content.

Comment: Ok so it's more about preparation and defining you `work materials' rather than on-the-go data assemblage. Thanks!